# V8 JavaScript Engine and Mac App Store

Tags: javascript, app-store, appstore-approval, mac-app-store, embedded-v8

If I embed the V8 JavaScript Engine in my application (a game) is it still possible to distribute it in the Mac & iOS App Stores?

Comment: V8 does not work on iOS, because it requires executable writable memory to JIT-compile code into.

Comment: So basically if I want to target iOS devices V8 is a no go? I wanted to use V8 to provide access to various native C++ methods from javascript. I'm curious, would JavaScriptCore on iOS stand in as a suitable replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you embed your own interpreter engine (any programming language), you will have to disable JIT (or any other dynamic executable code generation), as writing executable code will not work in the app sandbox on stock OS iOS devices.  Compiler engines are not allowed.  An app with an interpreter also can not have any code download capability, or it will be rejected by Apple.  So you will have to embed your complete game with your interpreter for submission to Apple's App store.

But there are many apps approved and in the app store with embedded interpreters (Basic, for instance).